# Deliver application's GUI via browser

Tags: virtualization, remote-server, rdp, citrix

I need to show to a user an interface of some application running on a server using a browser. It should be like RDP-client for a single application on a server.

Are there any solutions or services that can implement following functionality? Maybe Citrix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what you're looking for:

http://freerdp.net/

> About FreeRDP-WebConnect
>
> FreeRDP-WebConnect is an open source gateway for accessing RDP
>   sessions using any HTML5 compliant browser. In particular it relies on
>   the Canvas and the WebSockets feature. FreeRDP-WebConnect is a
>   subproject of the FreeRDP project.
>
> On the server side, a standalone daemon - written in C++ - provides a
>   Web page via HTTPS (or HTTP, if configured) and uses FreeRDP libs to
>   connect as a client to any RDP session. The server side WebSockets
>   implementation handles current RFC6455 only, so browsers that
>   implement the older drafts do not work. With RFC6455 being raised to
>   the "Proposed Standard" level, this should change now really soon.

I would create an account on the server for the user, and only give it access to the one application it needs access to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know, does this application support multiple user access simultaneously?

Comment: I do not, but I would assume it does. I've never used it myself having never had the need. I found it on Google with a search, though I may play with it a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cameyo. To start, [create yourself a free account](http://online.cameyo.com), and click on "Add App". If your installer supports unattended installation, you simply need to submit it. Otherwise, you can build a Cameyo package locally and send it in. It will then be playable as HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate what server you are running on.

As an alternative to [FreeRDP-Webconnect](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP-WebConnect) cited above, also open source and also using FreeRDP as rdp client through an HTTP gateway, there is [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille).

FreeRDP-WebConnect embeds a standalone daemon written in C++ to provide a web page via HTTP(S), and so will also work on Linux servers, while Myrtille have a IIS/.NET (C#) implementation and an MSI installer, thus is more intended for Windows Servers.